# "Not faraway" for talking about a related matter

Tags: phrase-usage, expressions, phrase-choice

Can I use the expression "Not faraway" when wanting to talk about another matter that is strongly related to the previous one?

For example:

> She always appears in the most beautiful clothes ever. **Not faraway**, her sister gets out with very casual if not cheap clothes.

The two sentences are in contradict to each other, so "On the other hand" and similar expressions can perfectly work. But regardless that, I want to convey the initial description above.

"Faraway" has two meanings in which one is literal:

*A long way away*

While the other one is:

*If you have a faraway expression, you look as though you are not thinking about what is happening around you*

The meaning I want to achieve is not explicitly stated, besides that I want it in its negative form in order to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

Faraway is an adjective that has a first meaning of literally distant (as in *faraway lands*), and a second meaning of dreamy or preoccupied (as in *faraway look*). **Neither has to do with subject matter being related to other subject matter.**

Looking at your sentence, I would think that you had made a typo, and intended to say "Not far away, her sister..." with a meaning that her sister literally is not far from her.

"On the other hand" is a fine choice when making a comparison--why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Thank you, Katy, for clarifying the possible meanings of "faraway". I want to use it in a poem, and "On the other hand" would make it sounds like _a statement in a comprehension passage_ besides that its length is pretty long for what I've determined for each line to hold. I can go with the regular options such as "whereas" for example although I've wanted to use something new (to me) and idiomatic.

Comment: @TasneemZH You could use the construction "one... the other" like in the first paragraph of this fairytale about two sisters (Rose Red and Snow White) https://www.bartleby.com/17/2/42.html

Comment: Great! I will certainly read it and see their usage of that construction. Thank you!

Comment: *What **one** has she must share with **the other*** —Amazing! I probably should find some way to use it. And for what is worth mentioning, the two statements in my question body are not the poem ones, they are just some ordinary sentences.